# How to replace a set of strings in a sentence

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, sorting

I understand there are so many ways to replace strings in sentence for instance:

```
sentences= 'This is a sentence, even there may be a lot of sentence coming'
word_list = ["sentence", 'be', 'coming']

to_replace = ["changes"]  

res = ' '.join([to_replace if idx in word_list else idx for idx in sentences.split()])
 
print("After replace: " + str(res)) 

output: 'This is a changes, even there may changes a lot of 
         sentence changes'
```

but what i want is following:

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence, even there may be a lot of sentence coming'

word_list = ["sentence", 'be', 'coming']

to_replace = ['change1', 'change2', 'change3']
```

so output should be like:

```
output: 'This is a change1, even there may change2 a lot of sentence change3'
```

is it possible to only replace sentence with given string(to_replace) from string(word_list ) not other words in sentence even there may be repeted words in sentence ? say like "sentence" is repeated two times but i want to replace only one time, not for all word 'sentence'

UPDATE:

```
 k = []
 dummy = 'Lorem what your doing ? how are you guys doing ? dummy 
            me doing bad '

 for p1 in x1:
   for n1, n2 in zip(['Lorem', 'dummy'], ['hello', 'hai']):
      new = p1.replace(n1, n2)
      k.append(new)

  output: ['hello what your doing ? how are you guys doing ? dummy 
            me doing bad ',
           'Lorem what your doing ? how are you guys doing ? hai 
            me doing bad ']
```

in above example sentence getting repeated. please help i want only one sentence.

Comment: Yes, of course. Was there a particular difficulty when you tried to do it?

Comment: An obvious solution would be to iterate over all words in the sentence and if it matches the current word to be replaced, replace it and advance to the next word to be replaced.

Comment: yes having some difficulties. i updated my code please check

Comment: i have updated extra code which im working on please help.

Comment: I showed below. There is another argument in the replace method, where you can specify how many replacements to make for each word. Also, you don't have to split and join the string. Just use the original string and create a new object with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
sentences= 'This is a sentence, even there may be a lot of sentence coming'
word_list = ["sentence", 'be', 'coming']
to_replace = ['change1', 'change2', 'change3']  
d = dict(zip(word_list, to_replace))
new_r = re.sub('\w+', lambda x:d.pop((s:=x.group()), s), sentences)
```

Output:

```
'This is a change1, even there may change2 a lot of sentence change3'
```

Answer (score 1):

should see this work

```
def degistir(snt, wl, tr):
    if len(wl)==len(tr):
        for w,r in zip(wl, tr):
            snt=snt.replace(w, r)
    return snt
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you're looking for the zip function. Plus in the replace function, you can specify how many replacements to make. Also note, that strings are immutable,  so in the loop, it is actually creating a new string object with the same name.

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence, even there may be a lot of sentence coming'
word_list = ["sentence", 'be', 'coming']
to_replace = ['change1', 'change2', 'change3']

for old_word, new_word in zip(word_list, to_replace):
    sentence = sentence.replace(old_word, new_word, 1)
print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
This is a change1, even there may change2 a lot of sentence change3
```

Answer (score 1):

No error management whatsoever:

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence, even there may be a lot of sentence coming'

word_list = ["sentence", 'be', 'coming']

to_replace = ['change1', 'change2', 'change3']

start = 0
for idx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    pos = sentence.find(word, start)
    if pos:
        sentence = sentence.replace(word, to_replace[idx], 1)
    start = pos + 1

print(sentence)
```

This yields

```
This is a change1, even there may change2 a lot of sentence change3
```